# Chrome fails to create folder - javascript fs.mkdir

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mkdir

I want to create a folder. Using below when I run javascript from command it works ok. But from chrome it fails to create a folder.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
    function myfunction(){

    var fs = require("fs");

    console.log("Going to create directory /tmp/test");
    fs.mkdir("/xyz",function(err) {
       if (err) {
          return console.error(err);
       }
       console.log("Directory created successfully!");
    });

    }   
  
  </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  <h1>Dhruv's Extension</h1>
  <input type = "button" onclick = "myfunction()" value = "Click to create directory">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no `fs` module in the browser (it's a Node.js module), there's no way that can work.

Comment: Browsers can write files, not directories, using the new [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Comment: `fs` is an inbuilt NodeJS module. AFIK, browser will not allow you to access the local files directly using a file path in the system. Instead one has to use the browser's filePicker api to open the finder/explorer, which will give you a handler for the selected file.